# protected $table = 'users'; Not being respected in relationship on a model extending from User?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, laravel-query-builder

Currently I have this "ContactLine" model that is extending from the User model

```
class ContactLine extends User
{
    use HasFactory;
    
    protected $table = 'users';

    public function organizations(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Organization::class);
    }
}
```

I have written a test controller where I am trying to inject the ContactLine into the method via route model binding.

```
class TestContactlineControler extends Controller
{
    public function __invoke(ContactLine $contact)
    {
        return $contact;
    }
}
```

However I am currently getting this error whenever I try to hit the route for this controller

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'incidents.contact_line_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `incidents` where `incidents`.`contact_line_id` = 1 and `incidents`.`contact_line_id` is not null and `closed_at` is null and `incidents`.`deleted_at` is null)
```

However if I change the controller to inject the User model instead it works fine.
In my user model I have this relationship which I think is causing the error.

```
   public function incidents(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Incident::class);
    }
```

However I thought setting the table to users in either User or ContactLine model should make it so it looks for incidents.user_id not incidents.contact_line_id

Answer (score 0):

You can define the fields that are used to lookup a releation by settings the second and third param of `hasMany`
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

By default, laravel will do a lookup depending on your ClassName, by settings the params you can bypass this.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I thought the protected $table = 'users' means I Should not have to do this?

Comment: @meowzart For the connection to your table: yes, but you want to define a relation for multiple models with different names to the same origin, so you have to define the name in the relation.